# Wrapping a Tkinter program in a scroll bar

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, scrollbar

I am trying to incorporate a scrollbar in my Tkinter window so as I add more things the user can scroll down. From what I've read so far it seems I need to use a Listbox widget but running into trouble adding the scrollbar as it is only getting added to the bottom of the program and not wrapping the entire thing? My code is below.

```
import Tkinter as Tk
from Tkinter import StringVar

class SampleApp(Tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.button = Tk.Button(self, text="Get", command=self.on_button)
        self.button.pack()#place(x=150, y=600)
####Name#####
        labelText=StringVar()
        labelText.set(" Name")
        labelDir=Tk.Label(self, textvariable=labelText, height=1)
        labelDir.pack()

        directory=StringVar(None)
        self.name =Tk.Entry(self,textvariable=directory,width=25)
        self.name .pack()
    def on_button(self):
        with open('filename.html', 'w') as myfile:
            myfile.write('The button worked')

app = SampleApp()
scrollbar = Tk.Scrollbar(app)
scrollbar.pack( side = Tk.RIGHT, fill=Tk.Y )
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `Scrollbar` widget is only implemented for `Canvas`, `Listbox`, and `Text` widgets. The `Scrollbar` must be configured to one of those widgets, and then you add widgets to that parent. Unfortunately, it's not the most straightforward widget to use. See [Effbot's `Scrollbar` page](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm) for an example.

Comment: but then can I add entry widgets inside the listbox widget?

Comment: I like to start with the `root` object, put a `Canvas` in there with a `Scrollbar`, then put a `Frame` in the `Canvas`, then put all the little widgets into the `Frame`.